# Multiple Definition with Identical Signatures

Tags: vb.net

```
Dim WithEvents client As New WebClient
Private Sub DirectX9ToolStripMenuItem_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles DirectX9ToolStripMenuItem.Click
    Try
        client.DownloadFileAsync(New Uri("http://download1588.mediafire.com/y9phz64wph4g/aqlp1m71mvuwo74/Direct+X+11+Update.rar"), "C:\Documents and Settings\All Users\Documents\Direct X 11 Update.RAR")
    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox("File already exists or is corrupted!")
    End Try
End Sub

Private Sub client_DownloadFileCompleted(sender As Object, e As AsyncCompletedEventArgs) Handles client.DownloadFileCompleted
    MsgBox("Direct X 9 has been successfully downloaded!", MsgBoxStyle.Information)
    Label48.Visible = False
    Label49.Visible = False
    ProgressBar3.Visible = False
    Label48.Text = "0 &"
    Label49.Text = "0 / 0"
    ProgressBar3.Value = 0
End Sub


Private Sub client_DownloadProgressChanged(sender As Object, e As DownloadProgressChangedEventArgs) Handles client.DownloadProgressChanged
    Label48.Visible = True
    Label49.Visible = True
    ProgressBar3.Visible = True
    Label48.Text = ProgressBar3.Value & "%"
    Label49.Text = e.BytesReceived & " / " & e.TotalBytesToReceive
    ProgressBar3.Value = e.ProgressPercentage

End Sub

Private Sub GeForceExperienceV2000ToolStripMenuItem_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles GeForceExperienceV2000ToolStripMenuItem.Click

    Try
        client.DownloadFileAsync(New Uri("http://download903.mediafire.com/w91mlqdf6clg/a540a35f5ddcpbn/GeForce_Experience_v2.2.2.0.exe"), "C:\Documents and Settings\All Users\Documents\GeForce_Experience_v2.2.2.0.exe")
    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox("File already exists or is corrupted!")
    End Try
End Sub

Private Sub client_DownloadFileCompleted(sender As Object, e As AsyncCompletedEventArgs) Handles client.DownloadFileCompleted

    MsgBox("GeForce_Experience_v2.2.2.0 has been successfully downloaded!", MsgBoxStyle.Information)
    Label48.Visible = False
    Label49.Visible = False
    ProgressBar3.Visible = False
    Label48.Text = "0 &"
    Label49.Text = "0 / 0"
    ProgressBar3.Value = 0

End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: So...your question is what?

Comment: You have 2 `client_DownloadFileCompleted` events - do you not see them? You can't do that!

Comment: sorry.. i just learn VB :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You got your answer in comments but just going to explain to make sure you understand what you can and can't do.

When you create a method you name it so that when you call it your program knows which one it is you want to call. When you name 2 methods the same way it does not know which one to use when it is called.

The only way to have 2 methods with the same name is if they have a different "signature" that means it can't be 100% identical. Different parameters will make your method's signature different even if they are called the same